# HTML form on Google Maps on click

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps

I'm new to Google maps and I'm wondering how would I program a Map which would pop out a HTML form when the user clicked a location on the map? I'd like the form to "pop out" of the map on screen. is this possible?

I've got the following...

```
         <script>
        var contentString = '<div id="content">
       <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
       <b>Name</b><br/> <input type="text" name="fname" />
       <br/><b>Description</b><br/>
       <TEXTAREA NAME="description" COLS=40 ROWS=6></TEXTAREA><br/><br/>
       <b>Latitude</b><br/><INPUT name="lat" id ="lat" /><br/>
       <b>Longitude</b><br/><INPUT name="lng" id ="lng" /><br/>
       <input type="submit" />
       </form>
       </div>';
```

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

My on click listener is...

```
GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, latLng)
{
    if (latLng) {
 marker = new GMarker(latLng, {draggable:true});
 map.addOverlay(marker);
 infowindow.open(latLng, map);
  }

    // display the lat/lng in your form's lat/lng fields
    document.getElementById("lat").value = latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById("lng").value = latLng.lng();
});

  }
}
```

What I want is on click It'll open a HTML form at the location where the user clicked and pass on the lat/lng fields to the HTML form. is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean something like the example on this page: http://www.garshol.priv.no/blog/17.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the information you need is [in the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows), along with [an example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple.html) - all you need to do is put the HTML form in there.

Comment: Can I not have it so the form would appear if the user was to click at a point on that map which wasnt an icon?

Comment: umm, could you explain with some code? I', really unsure what you mean. Sorry, new to Google maps API :(